# Is it legal to use the same Windows 7 key for a guest OS on a host with same key

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, license

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Windows 7 licensing work for running the OS as Virtual Machines?](https://superuser.com/questions/25678/how-does-windows-7-licensing-work-for-running-the-os-as-virtual-machines)

Is it legal to use the same Windows 7 key for a guest OS on a host with same key.
I mean physically speaking, it is the same machine.

Does the licence discriminate virtualized hardware?

Comment: Also see http://serverfault.com/questions/53380/can-a-windows-7-ultimate-product-key-be-used-for-virtual-machines-as-well over on serverfault for some more info :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The license covers running ***one*** installation of the operating system.  Running a VM of Win 7 inside Win 7 would constitute ***two*** installations.