# Is it possible to use Windows 7 64-bit key on 32bit simultaneously?

Tags: windows-7, license, windows-activation

I have my laptop which got Windows 7 64-bit OS. For development purposes I have installed Windows 7 32bit on VirtualBox on same laptop.

Is it possible to use same key for 32-bit OS on VirtualBox while having 64bit Windows on laptop?

Comment: its not allowed to use the same key twice, let alone 64bit/32bit.

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/273605/19943

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Technically yes.

Legally no. You are breaking the EULA.

You can use the same key on 32 or 64 bit Windows of the same edition (e.g. Home Premium, Professional etc.). But, unless you have MSDN or similar, you are only allowed one installation.

Comment: I disagree based on experience: For OEM licenses, I cannot use a 64 bit key on a 32 bit version, and vice versa

Comment: @Luke - You should have no problems using an OEM key on 32 bit or 64 bit as long as it is another OEM disk of the same service pack level and you are using the correct edition.... The keys are interchangeable and fully legal. Sometimes there were big price differences and if I fully managed the IT in the company, I would purchase the other edition and use the key on my media - it works very well.

Comment: I've had activation errors if I, for example, use the Windows 7 key on the side of a computer and install a 32 bit version instead of the 64. I see from the link below it doesn't matter, and MS is confirming it in that thread, so I guess I'm inforrect... And that's why I didn't downvote this answer

Comment: @Luke - Ok - that is a manufacturer locked OEM copy which is slightly different... e.g. if Dell, you should be able to use 32 or 64 bit dell windows disks, but you wouldn't be able to use Acer or generic OEM...

Comment: @Luke - What you describe sounds like an issue that could have been solved if you called Microsoft or as William points out you were trying to use a Dell OEM key on a HP Desktop.  Going forward with Windows 8, the key will actually be contained with the bios, so mistakes like that will be harder to have.  It also means the key itself will be locked to the motherboard, its unclear, you likely simply get a new key if the motherboard is replaced by HP.

Comment: @WilliamHilsum On the same machine, I've attempted it... That's why I look for the `Program Files (x86)` folder on their hard drive if I can access it

Comment: @Luke - sorry, little bit confused on your last comment... Going to bed now, feel free to go to chat tomorrow and @ me - I can discuss it then rather than clog up comments!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, and you can't since:

> You can't install 32 bit one computer and install 64 bit on another computer using the same key.

[For your more reference](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/is-a-windows-7-license-key-valid-for-both-32-bit/70d546cd-b6e3-44d8-a6c8-fd7feb7d1915)

Comment: This answer is incomplete. You can do this its just not allowed. Which means the second copy would not be able to be activated so you would be better of using just a trial. Microsoft has FREE Windows 7 Virtual Machines on their website, they are all trials, and they outline how to use them.  Its an attempt to offer ways to test your website against IE, because the virtual machines are listed by what IE is installed, of course you can create your own virtual machine with a Windows 7 trial on it also.

Comment: @Ramhound but the question is whether the key can be applicable or not?

Answer (score -2):

You can absolutely do it, Since its on Virtual box.

Comment: Why does that make a difference? Does the Windows 7 licence specifically allow doing that?

Comment: This answer is incomplete.  It would also be "possible" if you were running VMWare or Virtual PC built into Windows 7.  What is possible and allowed by the license is entirely different.

Comment: The Windows licence specifically forbids using the use of one licence on two machines at the same time, that includes real and virtual machines. Just because the virtual machine is running on the same hardware does not matter as far as the EULA is concerned, what you are doing is illegal.