# Does VirtualBox takes up a Windows license key?

Tags: windows-7, windows, virtualbox, license

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Windows 7 licensing work for running the OS as Virtual Machines?](https://superuser.com/questions/25678/how-does-windows-7-licensing-work-for-running-the-os-as-virtual-machines)

I have Windows 7, 3 cd-keys.
I use one on this PC, but i want to have a win7 virtual machine in virtualbox (that can go on internet). Is it gonna bring me down another key?

Comment: To legally register an install of Windows 7, you'll need to use up a key, even in a virtual machine such as virtualbox.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will use a key since you need one licence/key per installation. Not one per computer.