# How to test out Windows 7 applications to see if you like them?

Tags: windows-7, windows, software-rec, windows-registry, file-management

When a portable version of a Windows 7 application is *not* available, what is an effective way to test it out to see if you like it?

*I define **effective** as:*

1. Not time consuming
2. Leaves no (or minimal) files and folders behind if uninstalled
3. Leaves no (or minimal) registry entries changed or added if uninstalled
4. Does not remove files or registry entries that were present before evaluating the application

I used to take a registry and file structure **snapshot** before and after trying out any application, and then compare everything after the install or uninstall.  This did not satisfy #1 above, and required many judgement calls, especially for registry entries.

I then switched to creating **System Restore points**.  But I'm always concerned they will mess something up.  And after installing the *(disappointing and misleading)* free version of Microsoft OneNote 2013, and then removing it by restoring a System Restore point, there was still a significant amount of cleanup that had to be performed by hand (as well as a bunch of new \Windows\assembly folders that I'm really not sure if I should delete).

I would prefer a **free (as in no cost) solution**.  The solution can use tools built into Windows 7 or not.

The solution must be legal, and must work on a system on which the Windows 7 operating system was pre-installed by the manufacturer (no Windows installation disks included).  If the answer includes setting up a VM, please ensure that it will work with this condition.

*Technically, if the answers others post use tools and techniques that are built into the OS, then this question belongs here in the Superuser site, and if the answers use tools that are not built into the OS, then this question belongs on the Software Recommendations SE site.  Since there will likely be complaints if it is crossposted, and I can't predict the answers, I'll post the above question here.  If the mods want to crosspost it, they have my permission to do so.*

Comment: Added text to clarify how this is different from a previous question posted by another user.

Answer (score 5):

**Use a virtual machine** and prior to installing the application to be trialled, take a snapshot of the VM. Once you're done testing the program, roll the VM back to the snapshot point.

Some virtualization products even support differencing features that let you build a *parent* VM and then create a *child* that essentially tracks only the changes made to the parent. In your case, you could create a child before testing your app, then simply delete it when done (no "rolling back" required).

Comment: Does a VM require another Windows 7 license?  If not, can a preinstalled Windows 7 environment (installed by the manufacturer) be used in the VM (on the same machine)?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard To run Windows 7 in a VM, you would need either 1) A second Windows license, or 2) Virtualization rights. Have a look at this [SuperUser question](http://superuser.com/questions/25678/how-does-windows-7-licensing-work-for-running-the-os-as-virtual-machines)