# How to upgrade SSD with windows 11 without losing offline licence?

Tags: ssd, windows-11, privacy, license

I'm planning to buy a laptop with Windows 11 and immediately upgrade SSD. I assume I will be able to use the laptop initially without creating online windows account (and I strongly prefer this for privacy). However, I have no idea what will happen when I will upgrade SSD. Can windows 11 licence be somehow retained without using online Microsoft account?

Comment: I think you are somewhat misinformed.  (1) The Microsoft is a secure as a local account if not more so.  (2) the licensing is in the licensing server so you can easily change the disk.

Comment: Of course  @John I'm in lack of information, why else whould I ask things :)
However, please clarify your points, they are quite unusual. 
1) Local account is OK with me, this is what I'm willing to use. I don't want to connect it with online account. 
2) When I remove the system disk with windows-11, how will the licencing server know that the new disk with new windows iso installed is in the machine I legally bought with windows, and not in some other machine?

Comment: Make sure you have internet when you install the disk and the licensing server will find your license.  Also fully secure your local account as it is generally easier to break into

Comment: Thanks. Does it work simply by MAC address? Sounds quite insecure..

Comment: I am surprised by the comments here (For OEM machines) . Im pretty sure The Microsoft license is embedded in the motherboard - so a fresh reinstall will work just fine.   Definately not bound to MAC address.

Comment: thank you @davidgo, - I had no idea that windows licence is stored in UEFI/BIOS, and thought that removing ssd will remove it. Found the info here: https://superuser.com/questions/1108151/windows-license-stored-in-uefi-bios - it is the answer to my question. Do you want to write it down, or should I do it myself?

Comment: Just changing the SSD should not invalidate any licencing in Windows. I've simply cloned a current install to a new disk before now and then taken out the old one.

Comment: It’s impossible to loose your Windows license. How Windows 11 is activated is identical to Windows 10, it’s automatic, you just install Windows 11 on the new SSD and it will automatically activate. The Windows license absolutely is NOT stored in UEFI. It’s store in the ACPI table.